# Display specific div content in a Html from android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, performance

From a webpage which looks like :

```
    <html>
    ...........

    <div class="post-header"> ....................</div>

    ........

</html>
```

i want to display the content inside only that blog specified by `<div > </div>` tag  excluding rest of the other contents ..

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not shure but is this a case for [Mediaqueries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)?!

Comment: i am not familiar with your term Mediaqueries but what i need to do is  show the content of <div class = "BestElven">.. </div>  from this site  http://www.whoscored.com/    excluding rest of the other page

Comment: "how" or "what do you use" to show it? a special browser or an iframe? or your own programm grabbing the source?

Comment: You probably have to grab the page, edit it locally with regex and then send the manipulated version to your web view.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html